# install application during project start

Tags: c#, node.js, batch-file, asp.net-web-api, jsreport

scenario:
I'm working with Asp.net Web Api and using Jsreport as a reporting tool which can be installed using cmd. here are few steps.
1. Install node and npm first
2. open cmd and run cmd as "npm install jsreport"
3. Initialize using cmd as "node node_modules/jsreport --production"
4. and now start reporting server as "npm start --production"

Here jsreport exist outside the application folder directory and I have to provide the path of jsreport for my project to make my stuff done which doesn't  seems quite good. Now I have to do is to install application (JsReport) when my asp.net web api start for the first time if it(jsreport) doesn't exist. I have heard about .bat file which can be written to automate my jsreport installation when my project start but, I lack ideas about that.

Can anyone help me to get me out of this problem ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this with the following approach:

1. zip your locally installed node application (jsreport) into a single file
2. include the file into your solution
3. include also node.exe in the solution
4. set to both files Copy To Output = always
5. decompress the zip during the application start
6. run the process "node.exe server.js" using c#

This the same way how [jsreport.Embedded](http://jsreport.net/learn/net-embedded) works.

Comment: its fine till step 5 but got an error when I run the process like "System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("node.exe server.js");".... is there any thing I'm missing ? The error says "The system can not find the file specified."

Comment: You need to set the full path to the bin folder and also working directory of the process. Check this https://github.com/jsreport/net/blob/0.8.1/jsreport/jsreport.Embedded/EmbeddedReportingServer.cs#L248